# Create form input using modal in yii2 does not validate

Tags: forms, validation, yii, yii2, simplemodal

**controller**

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Ceremonia();
  if ($this->request->isPost) {
     if ($model->load($this->request->post()) && $model->save()){ Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('info',[' Nombre <strong>insertado</strong> correctamente!!!']); return $this->redirect(['index']); 
   }}else{ $model->loadDefaultValues();}
  if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax) { 
    return $this->renderAjax('create',['model' => $model]); }else{ return $this->render('create',['model' => $model]); 
   }
 }
```

Index file in the project:
**Index**

```
<?= Html::button('<i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Insertar',['value'=>Url::to('create'),'class' => 'btn btn-info','data-toggle'=>'modal','data-target'=>' ajax','id'=>'ModalButtonCreate']); ?>

<?php  
  Modal::begin(['title'=>'Insertar', 'id'=>'modalCreate', /*'size'=>'modal-lg',*/]);
  echo '<div id="modalContentCreate"></div>';
  Modal::end();
?>
```

main.js file in the project:
**main.js**

```
$(function(){
 $('#ModalButtonCreate').click(function(){  
     $('#modalCreate').modal('show').find('#modalContentCreate').load($(this).attr('value'));
  }); 
});
```

AppAsset file in the project:
**AppAsset**

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle {
     public $basePath = '@webroot';
     public $baseUrl = '@web';
     public $css = ['css/site.css',];
     public $js = ['js/main.js',];
     public $depends = ['yii\web\YiiAsset','yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset',]; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not put the "**Create**" file code here for review. It would be better to put it instead of AppAsset. Because apparently your medal works well
The available codes only indicate that by clicking on the button, the medal window will be displayed. The "Create" page is then rendered via the Ajax `load` method in jQuery.

On the "Create" page, you must use `ActiveForm` or active methods in the Html library, such as `activeInput` in the form, to use the model class or 'ActiveRecord' class. For example, the `save()` method in 'ActiveRecord' and the `validate()` method in 'model' or 'ActiveRecord'.
*** Depending on your use of `($model->load($this->request->post()) && $model->save())`

> Note: consider using ActiveForm in case you're dealing with models and need validation. [link](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-html#forms)

> There are two groups of input methods. The ones starting with active, which are called active inputs, and the ones not starting with it. Active inputs take data from the model and attribute specified, while in the case of a regular input, data is specified directly. [link](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-html#input-fields)

[Here](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/806/render-form-in-popup-via-ajax-create-and-update-with-ajax-validation-also-load-any-page-via-ajax-yii-2-0-2-3)'s a complete guide to rendering Form in popup via AJAX (Create and Update) with ajax

Good luck